# TypeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

I have a Google Appengine Project using Python2.7 and Django1.2 on Eclipse, that allows the user to use a form to upload a picture, resize it, and store it as a BLOB field.

I added a breakpoint where I indicated below, and saw  "file['content']" showing a value " TypeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is not subscriptable" in the Expressions view.

When I step into or over this line, it jumps to the error handler.

Can someone please advise how I can fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
if req.method == 'POST':
    try:
        u_form = UserInfoForm(req.POST)
        if not u_form.is_valid():
            return err_page(_('Error'))

        u = coffeeuser.CoffeeUser.all().filter('user =', user_info).get()
        u.nickname = user_info.nickname()
        u.realname = req.POST.get('real_name')
        u.phone = req.POST.get('phone')
        u.address = req.POST.get('address')
        if req.FILES.get('photo_file'):                
            file = req.FILES.get('photo_file')
            img = images.Image(file['content'])   <<<Breakpoint...Error occurs here
            img.resize(width=50, height=50)
            resized_img = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
            u.photo_file = db.Blob(resized_img)
        u.put()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
    except Exception, x:
        return err_page(_('Error'))
```

And here is the dump of the Console window as this happens. I don't see any error messages here.

INFO     2012-05-26 07:34:21,114 dev_appserver.py:2891] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
DEBUG    2012-05-26 07:35:15,960 dev_appserver.py:656] Matched "/user/" to CGI dispatcher with path main.py
DEBUG    2012-05-26 07:35:16,319 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1246] Enabling PIL: ['_imaging', '_imagingcms', '_imagingft', '_imagingmath']
DEBUG    2012-05-26 07:35:16,322 dev_appserver_import_hook.py:1246] Enabling django: []
DEBUG    2012-05-26 07:35:16,322 dev_appserver.py:1624] Executing CGI with env:
{'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://localhost:8080/user/', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'C1DFD96E', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/1.0', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'PATH_INFO': '/user/', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'http://localhost:8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '927730', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python27', 'TZ': 'UTC', 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'RememberMe=YPD/ztDwsHCs3J9cPG5c+g==; dev_appserver_login="test@example.com:False:185804764220139124118"; sessionid=2b5fc41e4c0332b1161a002ae12e616b; csrftoken=05e24dcb62093082dc1fafe66c0a6dbb', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.5', 'PATH_TRANSLATED': 'C:\_dev\eclipse-work\gae\pydev5\src\main.py', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryC4BfGc98AzYhJTQD', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'USER_ORGANIZATION': '', 'USER_ID': '185804764220139124118', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19', 'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8080', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 'USER_EMAIL': 'test@example.com', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~quizoncloud', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com', '_AH_ENCODED_SCRIPT_NAME': '/user/'}
DEBUG    2012-05-26 07:36:19,815 datastore_stub_index.py:181] No need to update index.yaml

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`file` is not a dictionary, so you can't do key lookup like that. Perhaps you mean `file.content`?

Although I don't think the object has a `content` attribute either - see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) for UploadedFile objects. Maybe you meant `file.read()`?

(Also, don't call your variable `file` - that hides the built-in `file` function).

Comment: Yes I should have used file.read(). That fixed the issue. Thank you. The world is a better place with you!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to add the line [[print 'DEBUG:>', file, type(file)]] just before the line that produce the exception. This error is about "file" object is not a mapping type.

Comment: I inserted the line as you suggested, but I don't see any output. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Instead I added two expressions: file and type(file) and the values are file = InMemoryUploadedFile: 10-20-2011 10-17-46 PM.jpg,

Comment: and type(file) = type: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>